# Search in a NSString for words that begin with specific text and end with a "

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, arrays, nsstring

I have a NSString that contains the html code of a webpage.
Now, how do i search on the whole string for all the words that start with 'data-src="http://' and end with a " ?
I'll save them in an array.
My string is called urlPage

PS: i dont want the words to have the 'data-src="http://' and " . I just want the words between these 2

Comment: you dont understand what i want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some example code:

```
NSString *string;
NSString *pattern;
NSRegularExpression *regex;

string = @" aa data-src=\"http://test1\" cd data-src=\"http://test2\" cd";
pattern = @"data-src=\"http://([^\"]+)\"";

regex = [NSRegularExpression
         regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
         error:nil];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"match: '%@'", [string substringWithRange:range]);
}
```

NSLog output:
match: 'test1'
match: 'test2'

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to search for string. Especially the `enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:` method. In this method you'll get the result that fits your regex and you can manually strip out the beginning part and the question mark if you want.