# Search a pattern in a NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pattern-matching, nsregularexpression

I want to search a pattern in a string. In the below code the pattern string '*' can be any character.

I got this sample code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268795/search-in-a-nsstring-for-words-that-begin-with-specific-text-and-end-with-a), but it's not working for me.

```
NSString *string;
NSString *pattern;
NSRegularExpression *regex;


string = @"img=img_1.png or it can be img=img.png";
pattern = @"img=*.png";

regex = [NSRegularExpression
         regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
         error:nil];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

NSLog(@"matches - %@", matches);

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
{
    NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"match: %@", [string substringWithRange:range]);
}
```

I want the optput string to be img_1.png & img.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your pattern to:

```
pattern = @"img=(.*?).png";
```

Comment: I got this o/p -> match: img_1.png or it can be img=img, where a i want img_1.png & img.png

Answer (score 0):

this pattern could work well:

```
NSString *pattern = @"(img=img[\\S]*\\.png)";
```

the matches are:

```
0 : {0, 13} - img=img_1.png
1 : {27, 11} - img=img.png
```

---

**OR**

with another pattern:

```
NSString *pattern = @"(img[^=][\\S]*png)";
```

the matches are (without the *img=* part):

```
0 : {4, 9} - img_1.png
1 : {31, 7} - img.png
```